# Find string contains only characters

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

How to find a string containing only characters?

E.g. the following detects only for digit,

```
SELECT *
  FROM dual
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('ABC2', '[^[:digit:]]');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with :alpha: instead of :digit:

http://psoug.org/reference/regexp.html

Comment: That is not documentation, this one is Oracle documentation http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following -

`regexp_like('value' ,'^[[:alpha:]]$')`

Where,

- ^ marks the start of the string
- [[:alpha:]] specifies alphabet class
- $ marks the end of the string